# Eloquent relation with two keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a team sports statistics project in Laravel.

Here is a sketch of the main models regarding this question:

```
class Team
    // belongsToMany matches
    // belongsToMany people

class Match
    // belongsToMany teams
    // belongsToMany people

class Person
    // belongsToMany matches
    // belongsToMany teams
```

I have also made models for the pivot tables to work directly with them. I have some stuff like `goals_scored`, `number`, `position` etc. stored there and it's too clumsy to use methods for updating pivot.

```
class MatchTeam  // Participation of a team in the match
    // belongsTo match
    // belongsTo team

class MatchPerson  // Participation of a person in the match
    // belongsTo match
    // belongsTo team
    // belongsTo person
```

Is there an Eloquent way to relate `MatchTeam` to `MatchPerson`? I don't want to introduce a direct `match_team_id` foreign key, I want to do this using the existing `match_id` and `team_id` fields on both of the tables.

Currently I have this in my MatchTeam model:

```
public function matchPeople()  // the roster
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Stats\MatchPerson', 'team_id', 'team_id')->where('match_id', $this->match_id);
}
```

It works fine. However, I am very concerned that this code is not fair to the nature of the relation - they are not related based on `team_id`, they are related based on both fields. I could have also written it like this:

```
public function matchPeople()  // the roster
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Stats\MatchPerson', 'match_id', 'match_id')->where('team_id', $this->team_id);
}
```

Is there a fair way in which I could specify relation based on two columns in Eloquent?

Of course, this question is more out of curiosity as the actual problem of making the method is conquered.

A usage example for the curious:

```
$teamA->goals_for = $teamA->matchPeople->sum('goals');
```